# Virtual File System Memory Block Creation

Tags: c, memory, filesystems

I'm working on a project where I need to create all the basic components for a virtual file system(memory blocks, filename table, inodes, etc). My system needs to be able to make a single-layer(no sub directories) "disk" which is composed of fixed memory blocks(in this case 256 bytes). I understand all the basic components and their functions as far as using the file system, but I'm unsure of how to start making blocks of memory for allocation.
I don't have a structure designed yet for the inodes or the file table(I am required to come up with my own) but I believe I have the basic memory allocation set for making a "disk" where I can then format and add the subsequent data structures:

```
int make_disk(char const *name)
{
    int c, dex;
    char buff[BLOKSIZE];

    if(!name)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Make: Invalid Name\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if((c=open(name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644)) < 0) 
    {
        perror("Cannot Open File\n");
        return -1;  
    }

    memset(buff, 0, BLOKSIZE);
    for(dex=0;dex<NUMBLOKS;dex++)
    {
        write(c, buff, BLOKSIZE);
    }

    close(c);
    return 0;

}
```

My main question is am I on the right track as far as correctly allocating 256-byte memory blocks that will be used for file storage and metadata storage once this "disk" is properly partitioned?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a memory mapped file to serve as the virtual disk.